# Autocomplete search example for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can someone point me in the direction of how to implement an "autocomplete" search interface on the iPhone. I am assuming I will need to use a NSTimer to periodically check what has been typed and then submit that partial string to my data source and then display those.

I need to connect it up with an existing web service returning JSON

A tutorial or some sample code would be preferred.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418592/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-search/1753710#1753710) will likely help you. If you are using a `UISearchDisplayController`, you would not need to use an `NSTimer` to poll the search field, as changes to the search field will fire delegate methods for you.

In those delegate methods, you may apply a new search predicate based on the contents of the field, and then refresh the data fetch and display possible words.

Comment: You don't *need* to use an `NSTimer` but using one allows you to limit the rate at which your app makes web-server requests. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23524397/242933

Comment: UPDATE: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` might work better than `NSTimer`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7061472/242933

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to "refresh the data fetch" pls

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values