# Implementing a search suggestions for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, database, search

I have a list of foods (e.g. apple, pear, banana, etc.). Suppose a user type "appl", I want my app to return the top 5 (the number 5 is arbitrary) closest results within this list. What is a good algorithm/data structure for implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get all the data from the database and store it in an array and then if you are using search bar -

```
(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

use this method and apply logic to search something like

```
for(NSString *curString in backUpArayForAllFiles) {
            flagCountForSearch++;
            if ([curString rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) 
            {
    }
    else 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is using a UISearchDisplayController to implement the UISearchDisplayDelegate protocol - and use NSPredicate (NSFetchResultsController) to filter through the table(s). 
I think this may help : [NSFetchedResultsController with search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418592/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-search/1753710#1753710)